# can't convert to json in python

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm sending this string to a falsk API with contentType: text/plain

```
{"KEY":"03029f14a8034656a6a9f27d9762ffcd","SHIPMENT_ID":"TestRef987d"}
```

I'm using contentType: text/plain because the sending system is old and can only use that type.

Now I would like to convert this string to json, so I do:

```
data = request.data
js = data.encode("utf-8")
j = json.loads(js)
return j["KEY"]
```

this gives back this error:

```
js = data.encode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Any help i very appreciated.

BR Kresten

Comment: If it's `bytes`, you'll need to `decode` it

Comment: Did the trick. Thanks. send an answer.